# AngularJS: Getting injected entity name programmatically

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to get an injected entity's name programmatically from its instance, be it controller, service or anything else that can be injected?

I obviously have the name already because I am injecting the entity based on its name, but I'd like to reduce the dependency on this hard-coded name to the injection line, for maintainability reasons.

This way I can construct logging and exception messaging without hard-coded names in them.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('MyController', ['myService', function(myService) {
  console.log('Service "' + myService.$name + '" made a terrible boo boo');
}]);
```

An obvious workaround would be to keep a constant even before the first line, and use it both for injection and messaging. I'm looking if there's a cleaner built-in angular way.

Comment: am suggesting [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) when comes to lazyloading. You can do your dependency injection rather.. lazily :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of a better answer, I'm going to answer my own question: No, seems that this is not available out of the box.

Feel free to update this post when a better answer becomes available.